# Android LVL License check cannot bind to service

Tags: android, android-intent

I have looked at ALL related questions and none fix my issue.

My issue first started when I tested by device on my Galaxy S2 running CM12 (A lollipop version of android WITH ALL of Google Play stuff installed).

Every time I tried to check my license, there would be an exception thrown. So I Googled the exception, which is about implicit and explicit intents. So I then modified my LicenseChecker.java class file to change the `bindService` intent.

I changed it to:

`Intent explicit = new Intent(ILicenseService.class.getName());
explicit.setPackage("com.google.vending");` as recommended [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1674).
I do not have Lucky Patcher installed on the device. I just found this via the Google search about the explicit intent exception.

Setting context to `getApplicationContext()` DOES NOT FIX IT.

The best part is:

On my Galaxy S5 running 4.4.2, NOT CHANGING THE CODE IN LICENSECHECKER.JAVA DOES NOT CAUSE A cannot bind to service ERROR!

I do still see the warning about implicit and explicit intents, however.

So I changed the code to make the intent explicit, and it causes the "cannot bind to service" error.

What am I missing and how do I fix this so it can run on Android 5.0+?
Why does Google provide code that doesn't even work with their OS?

Thanks everyone for your time! I hope someone can help me as I feel as if I tried everything.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Was just trying different things and this worked.

```
Intent explicit = new Intent(new String(Base64.decode("Y29tLmFuZHJvaWQudmVuZGluZy5saWNlbnNpbmcuSUxpY2Vuc2luZ1NlcnZpY2U=")));
                explicit.setPackage("com.android.vending");
```